# Can't connect to my server with restric RSYNC (RRSYNC)

Tags: perl, ssh, rsync

I explain my problem:

I used backuppc for remote some database on an other server and for saving my data I used rsync which uses ssh. On my remote server I put the ssh key of backuppc and it worked.

But I wanted to secure this connexion, so I used `rrsync` (a perl script for restrict the access), for a "read-only" access with copy.

So now, in the remote server I have in root/ssh/authorized_keys

```
command="/usr/local/bin/rrsync -ro /" ssh-rsa
```

But when I try to connect I have this message:

```
/usr/local/bin/rrsync: Not invoked via sshd
```

It's a message from the perl script, but I don't know what it means or what can I do for this to work.

Comment: How exactly were you trying to connect? In my case, I tried to connect via ssh just to check if I could still login, and received that same error. The reason was that ssh connected without any command to execute remotely, but rrsync prevents that with that strange error message. Executing `ssh ... user@server date` worked as intended (command denied).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, this message appears when you try to access the server with the restricted key without using rsync. It may be possible to edit the script to allow other programs, but I'm not skilled enough to attempt that.